# Why in the cutoff region of a CE NPN transistor we should have \$V_{B}<V_{E}\$?

Tags: transistors

In the cutoff region, the diode BE should be inversely biased, why? To make \$I_{B}≈0\$ but \$I_{B}\$ could still be zero even if \$V_{B}>V_{E}\$ because the condition for \$I_{B}\$ to be greater than zero is \$V_{B}\$ being greater than the depletion voltage of the BE diode , so what am I missing here?

Comment: What is the relationship between Vbe and Ib?

Comment: \$I_{B} \$ and \$V_{BE}\$ has the same V-I relation of a diode

Comment: Hmm okay. When does a diode have zero current flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \$I_{B}\$ could still be zero even if \$V_{B}>V_{E}\$

Yes, but \$V_{B}\$ can only be larger than \$V_{E}\$ by some 10s of mV.

> the condition for \$I_{B}\$ to be greater than zero is \$V_{B}\$ being greater than the depletion voltage of the BE diode

No. Using the Ebers-Moll equation for \$I_B\$

$$I_{B} = I_{S}[\frac{1}{\beta_F}(e^{V_{BE}/V_T}-1) +\frac{1}{\beta_R}(e^{V_{BC}/V_T}-1)]$$

and then setting \$I_B=0\$ rearranging, and using the name \$V_{BE0}\$ for the particular value of \$V_{BE}\$ which  gives \$I_B=0\$

$$\beta_R(e^{V_{BE0}/V_T} -1) + \beta_F(e^{V_{BC}/V_T} -1) = 0 $$

$$\beta_Re^{V_{BE0}/V_T}  + \beta_Fe^{V_{BC}/V_T} = \beta_R + \beta_F $$

$$\beta_Re^{V_{BE}/V_T}  + \beta_Fe^{V_{BE0}/V_T-V_{CE}/V_T} = \beta_R + \beta_F $$

$$e^{V_{BE0}/V_T}[\beta_R  + \beta_Fe^{-V_{CE}/V_T}] = \beta_R + \beta_F $$

$$e^{V_{BE0}/V_T}=\frac{\beta_R + \beta_F} {\beta_R  + \beta_Fe^{-V_{CE}/V_T}} $$

$$V_{BE0} = V_T ln\left(\frac{\beta_R + \beta_F} {\beta_R  + \beta_Fe^{-V_{CE}/V_T}}\right)$$

As \$V_{CE}/V_T\$ increases above 6, the above formula rapidly approaches the asymptote:

$$V_{BE0} = V_T \;ln\left(\frac{\beta_R + \beta_F} {\beta_R}\right)$$

$$V_{BE0} = V_T \;ln\left(1+\frac{\beta_F}{\beta_R}\right)$$

Arbitrarily choosing \$\frac{\beta_F}{\beta_R} = 30\$, and using \$V_T=26 mV\$, gives

$$V_{BE0} = 0.026\; ln\left(1+30\right)=0.089$$

$$V_{BE0} = 89 \;mV$$

So, according to this model, and assuming \$\frac{\beta_F}{\beta_R} = 30\$ and \$V_{CE} > 0.026*6 = 0.156\; V\$, i.e. \$V_{CE}>156\;mV\$, then \$I_B=0\$ when \$V_{BE} = 89\; mV\$. For any \$V_{BE}\$ greater than this, \$I_B\$ will be positive.

If we changed \$\frac{\beta_F}{\beta_R}\$ to equal 5, then \$V_{BE0}\$ would become 47 mV.

Answer (score 0):

You should remember/realize that the DEFINITION for saturation is not based on currents.
The saturation regions starts (npn case) as soon as the collector voltage Vc (against ground) falls below the base voltage Vb (against ground) - thus Vbc>0.

This happens when the voltage drop across the collector resistance Rc (as a result of rising collector current Ic) is large enough to make (Vcc-IcRc)<Vb.

In this case, the base current is drastcally increased because now it contains a second component (current through the forward biased B-C junction). As a consequence, the "classical" relationship between Ic and Ib (beta=Ic/Ib) does not apply anymore.

To answer your question in short: During saturation the base current is not zero. In contrary, it is larger than in "normal" operation.

**EDIT:** Sorry. What I have written is correct, however it did not answer your question, because I thought that you were asking about "saturation". I simply have confused saturation with cut.off.